# What kind of topological sorting exists in graph theory and what are their graphic plotting?

Tags: graph-theory

I know that there is at least two kinds of topological sorting: "by rank" and by"level"
a level of a vertex is the maximal length of a path with x as an extremity.
a rank of a vertex is the maximal length of a path which starts by x.

let's take for instance this oriented graph (two vertices must be change in order not to have a circuit consider X5 to X3 and solely X3 to X6)[image: graph]

Can you give two different topological sorting of it and plot them?

Comment: Why not make the changes you wish to eliminate circuits, and replace the existing (directed) graph with the revised one?

Comment: The device I use right now don't allow me to do it, but I will, I promise, it's a bit difficult on a tablet with http://www.webgraphviz.com/

Comment: In the meantime perhaps you can state what changes you would make?